# Get user meta on registration hook

Tags: user-meta, user-registration

How to get the user meta fields no registration hook in wordpress,
for examples we are registering the user in wordpress rest api, after user registration from mobile need to add function that get the user along with meta field values to perform some function in wordpress side.

added the user registration action hook "user_register" that returns the newly register user email, username and id etc, but unable to get the meta field values

```
   add_action( 'user_register', 'custom_registration_action', 10, 1 );

function custom_registration_action( $user_id ) {
    $user = get_userdata( $user_id );
    $schedule_time =  get_user_meta( $user_id, 'schedule_time', true );

    error_log($schedule_time);

}
```

Comment: How are you inserting the meta values, and how are you attempting to retrieve them? Can you add your code for each to your question.

Comment: @JacobPeattie  i'm trying to get the meta values inserted through rest endpoint using get_user_meta() function

Comment: Does this hook executed before the meta values inserted ?

Comment: No, it's not. But if there's something wrong with the way you're setting the values to begin with, or a mistake in your *actual* code, then it might be possible to find those issues. Otherwise all anyone can say is that what you want to do is possible but you're making a mistake or there's a conflict somewhere.

Comment: any wordpress function to return the complete user object including all the meta fields by user id ?

Comment: Are you just going to ignore me then? If that function, `get_userdata( $user_id )`, works then `get_user_meta()` should also work. So why not let people help find out what the actual issue is by sharing the actual code that's not working.

Comment: @JacobPeattie i've updated the code